# Global Directive on (change) prevents some bound methods local to a Component from running

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

We would like to `.trim()` all inputs in a rather large angular2 project. All of our forms are template-based, non-ReactiveForms. As I don't want to refactor every single input we have, I thought a Directive would be the way to go.

In addition, various Components attach `(input)` or `(change)` listeners (for example, to uppercase text in a field as a user types).

My implementation below is taken from [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L9BkYaLUuHiBFClZxOwk?p=preview) (written by an Angular contributor in response to [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9146)) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066523/114900) (which predates Angular2 Final and is not workable in its current state).

With the following code, *my component-level methods are not called any more* (like the input-to-uppercase one mentioned above).

*Edit*: It appears that at least some Component-level `(blur)` methods are still called.

I imagine I'm missing something like a call to pass on execution to the component?

I have tried:

- [Reordering my `declarations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416344/angular-2-directive-for-a-component-overrides-ng-content) and that didn't help,
- Implementing `ControlValueAccessor` instead of `DefaultValueAccessor`.

Perhaps something with the `forwardRef`?

**My Trim Directive:**

```
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
import { DefaultValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

const TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimValueAccessor),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[type=text]',
    host: { '(change)': 'trim($event.target.value)' },
    providers: [TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class TrimValueAccessor implements DefaultValueAccessor {

    onChange = (_: any) => {};
    onTouched = () => {};

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elementRef: ElementRef) {};

    trim(value: any): void {
        if (value) {
            value = value.toString().trim();
            this.writeValue(value);
        }
        this.onChange(value);
    };

    registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => any): void { this.onChange = fn; }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => any): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
    }
}
```

This is loaded globally with an entry to `NgModule[declarations]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know it: turns out there was a regression elsewhere (merged at the same time I began this feature) that broke the *other* features.

Side notes which may be relevant to someone:

- My final implementation `implements ControlValueAccessor` (rather than `DefaultValueAccessor`)
- I added a call to `this.onTouched();` bound to `(blur)` from the original linked Plunker.